# How to use the 'cite' attribute to display the URL using CSS only?

Tags: html, css, url

I need to make a cite attribute visible, ie. showing the url of a blockquote on my webpage. I was told to use only CSS, no html.

Here is what I am currently working with in the html:

```
<blockquote cite="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_television">
<p>text from wiki</p>
```

I thought the CSS would be something like: `cite href {display: inline-block;}`, but that's not working.

Comment: I think, if you want show your source you can simply add near `blockquote` one more line like `<h3>` for example and put there your source

Answer (score 3):

I think this is what you're after:

```
 blockquote:before {
   content: attr(cite);
 }
```

Here's an example with some additional styling: http://jsfiddle.net/fx4nw3q0/1/

Comment: Your unclosed HTML tags gave me cancer.  I'm sending you the medical bills. :)

Comment: Doh, my bad, er, I mean, I just wanted to be as faithful as possible to the mark-up as originally posted. :-)

Answer (score 1):

```css
blockquote:after {
  content: attr(cite);
  display: block;
}
```

You can use `attr(<name>)` to pull in attribute values into pseudo blocks by the attribute name.

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/xv0rrf1f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

You can show with [CSS ::after pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3A%3Aafter) selector.

```
blockquote::after{
  content:attr(cite)
}
```

and you can get url with css [attr function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/attr),

[DEMO JSBin](https://jsbin.com/muzarirero/edit?html,css,output)